# Probability you end up at the origin after taking $2n$ steps?

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics, random-walk

Starting at the origin on the line we take a step of unit to the left or to the right
with probability $\frac12$. We do this repeatedly with independent steps. If we take $2n$ steps, what is the
probability that we find ourselves back at the origin?

To end up at the origin, you'd have to take $n$ steps to the left and $n$ steps to the right in any order. So I think the answer is $C(2n, n)$. Is this right?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What progress have you made so far?  Letting $F$ be the number of forward steps in the $2n$ steps, can you find the distribution of this value?  Can you find the value that corresponds to ending up back at the origin?

Comment: edited my question to include the answer i believe to be correct!

Comment: Why don't you walk us through your rationale and thinking so we can help you

Comment: @StatsStudent: I did explain my rationale. To end up at the origin after 2n steps, you have to take n steps to the left and therefore n steps to the right. These steps can be taken in any order. That's why I use a combination. There are 2n total steps and you choose n to be left and n to be right.

Comment: I see it now.  I think my browser wasn't refreshed.  Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to consider the probability of $\frac12$ for each step.

That is $$\binom{2n}{n}\cdot \frac1{2^{2n}}.$$

Remark: The answer can't be $\binom{2n}{n}$ as that would exceed $1$.

Also, note that out of $2n$ step, we pick $n$ to be the left move. This corresponds to the Binomial distribution.